# voice sound during boot and at login

Tags: sound

ubuntu 22.04 new install - a voice (at first sounds German) speaks then my login appears, then an english voice reads the screen and makes sounds as I login with my password. How do I disable the voice?
The sound under accessibility screen reader is off.
Johnf

Comment: By default Ubuntu does not speak, what have you installed and or turned on?

Comment: I am not aware of anything I have installed that does anything like providing a voice.  But here is a list:
python3, wxPython, VbCode, thunderbird, pgadmin4, dbeaver, virtualbox, filezilla, chrome, icedtea web, nvidia.  That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 I started hearing a voice at boot up.  Of course that annoyed me.  Oh I'm sure it is helpful for someone with impaired vision.  But I didn't like it.
The fix is simple when you see the login screen there is a sound icon (upper right) just turn off the sound.  It did not effect any sound settings I have after login.
Johnf